# IIS rewrites BadRequest response data

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a tomcat managed spring application. The application uses a spring Exception handler to catch and handle exceptions. When this happens we rewrite the response status of the request to 400 for example. Here is an example from our handler.

```
@ExceptionHandler({StepAlreadyInPlanException.class})
  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  public ErrorObject stepAlreadyInPlan(Exception ex) {
    log.log(Level.ERROR, new Date().toString(), ex);

    ErrorObject err = new ErrorObject();
    err.setErrorCode(400);
    err.setMessage("STEP_ALREADY_IN_PLAN_EXCEPTION");

    return err;
  }
```

This works really well in development where we use intelliJ to run the server. When we try the same code in our production setting on tomcat the response is swallowed and we see only "BadRequest" in the response data.

If we change our code so that the HTTP status header returns OK like so `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)`. We get the full data.

I suspect that tomcat is some how interfering with the request and silences our response. How can I configure tomcat to let this type of data trough?!

I intially suspected this to be a tomcat rewrite but after solving the problem I now know it was IIS that rewrote the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reconfigure the IIS httperrors config and set existingResponse to passTrough.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to configure your production web sever (`apache server` or `IIS`...) not tomcat.

Some of your webserver's configuration intercepts tomcat error responce and redirect it to a custom page of its own.

All you have to do is to override that configration or delete it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your app is configured to serve a static page when you have an error, and that is causing some conflict between Spring, your servlet container, and your static web server (if you have one).

Take a look at this:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/404-error-code-is-not-working-in-spring-mvc/